# When I upload products with images using csv on magento 2.2.6. The error is showing

Tags: magento2.2.6

*Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions.*

and `error_log` showing

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mindbsoul/public_html/staging/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php(2055): Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\MediaGalleryProcessor->saveMediaGallery(Array)


[21-Feb-2019 14:10:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot unpack array with string keys in /home/mindbsoul/public_html/staging/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/MediaGalleryProcessor.php:112
```

Comment: Have you got solution ?. I am getting same error.